# Assets modal window doesn't appear for WYGWAM insert image dialog

Tags: assets

I recall when I installed Assets 1, WYGWAM's insert image dialog would then pull up the Assets file picker. That doesn't happen with Assets 2.0.5.

I'm using WYGWAM 2.7 on EE2.5.5.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must force WYGWAM to use Assets and not File Manager:

Modules > WYGWAM > Settings - choose Assets obviously :P